# Hashed passwords updated through JDBC become corrupt. (More of encoding problem than hashing)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sha1

I've tried the following with MySQL UTF-8 and Latin-1, to no avail.

I hash my passwords (in this case toSecurify) using SHA-1 like so:

```
  if(toSecurify == null) {
   throw new Exception("toSecurifyString must not be null");
  }
  try {
   MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
   byte[] sha1HashBytes = new byte[40];
   messageDigest.update(toSecurify.getBytes(), 0, toSecurify.length());
   sha1HashBytes = messageDigest.digest();
   return new String(sha1HashBytes, "UTF-8");
  } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
   throw new Exception("Hash algorithm not supported.");
  } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
   throw new Exception("Encoding not supported.");
  }
```

Then I store this in the mysql database password column.

Now here's the tricky part I can query the db kind of like:
Is there any record with

```
username=<insertUserName> and password = thatHashFunctionUpThere(<insertPassword>);
```

This works great.

But now, updating records looks something like this:

```
String userName = someJdbcStuffToGetUsername();
String password = someJdbcStuffToGetPassword();

update(userName, password);
```

The password has now changed! This corrupts the passwords. 
It's like on the way out (when querying for it) it gets corrupted, but never on the way in. 
I say this because inserts and queries work great, but when I get the value out then set it again, it corrupts it, so it must be on the way out.

Does anyone have any thoughts? 
Where on the way out should I look for encoding issues?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Are you re-hashing the already hashed password on update by mistake?

Comment: That's a good suggestion Steve, but no, I'm not. :|

Comment: Just to clarify: the reads no longer work after an update? I.e. the password has changed in the DB and not just in your update code?

Comment: Well, you can read that row, but the password has been corrupted in the db, meaning they can't log in. So what I think is happening, is on the way (in a read) it gets corrupted, then I put that corrupted value back into the user, when updating them.

Comment: seems unlikely that it's a DB issue, more likely to be in code. Two suggestions: 1) Debug the code and see if the values retrieved from the DB is correct in the update method and if so, where it changes. 2) use mySQL client to do an insert/read/update set and see if that works

Comment: It's really hard to tell, it's hashed and so when displayed in mysql, comes out as question marks and garbellygook. It has to be coming out of the db into java land as corrupted. I know this because I'm simply taking what comes out, and saving it back into the db. It has to be on the way out. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

There's a flaw in your code.

> ```
> return new String(sha1HashBytes, "UTF-8");
> ```

You shouldn't be treating the bytes as characters. You should in fact convert every byte to a 2-character hexstring. E.g.

```
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(sha1HashBytes.length * 2);
for (byte b : sha1HashBytes) {
    if ((b & 0xff) < 0x10) hex.append("0");
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
return hex.toString();
```

But, better is to just use MySQL's own [`SHA1()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) function. On `INSERT` do:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, SHA1(?))";
// ...
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(username);
preparedStatement.setString(password); // This one should be unhashed!!
int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
// ...
```

and on `UPDATE`:

```
String sql = "UPDATE user SET username = ?, password = SHA1(?) WHERE id = ?";
// ...
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(username);
preparedStatement.setString(password); // This one should be unhashed!!
preparedStatement.setLong(id);
int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
// ...
```

and on `SELECT`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = SHA1(?)";
// ...
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(username);
preparedStatement.setString(password); // This one should be unhashed!!
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Using prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)